# Unable to delete cookie using Next.js server side action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to delete a cookie using the next/headers module in a Next.js application, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's the code snippet:

```
import {cookies} from "next/headers";
export default async function Signout() {
    async function deleteTokens() {
       "use server"

        cookies().delete('accessToken')
    }

  await deleteTokens()
  return (
      <></>
  );
}
```

I expected the cookies().delete('accessToken') line to delete the cookie named "accessToken", but it doesn't seem to have any effect. The cookie is still present after the function is executed.

I am getting following error: Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options

But i have set the "use server" and enabled it in the next.config.js

#using Next.js 13.4.4

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your function runs as part of the server component, not as a server action. You can execute your function as a server action by passing it down to a client component and calling it from a client component on page load.

```js
// app/signout/page.js

import { cookies } from "next/headers";

import SignOutAction from "./SignOutAction";

export default async function SignOut() {
  async function deleteTokens() {
    "use server";

    cookies().delete("accessToken");
  }

  return <SignOutAction deleteTokens={deleteTokens} />;
}
```

```
// app/signout/SignOutAction.js

"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function SignOutAction({ deleteTokens }) {
  const deleteTokensRef = useRef(deleteTokens);

  useEffect(() => {
    deleteTokensRef.current = deleteTokens;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    deleteTokensRef.current();
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

P.S. This is not directly related to your original question, but this implementation is prone to CSRF vulnerability - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62769/should-login-and-logout-action-have-csrf-protection

Comment: So if my server action is called by a server component (to fetch data at page load), it cannot delete the cookie?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about it - you can only delete cookies in a Server Action or Route Handler | https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#deleting-cookies

Comment: I read that a few times but it's still not clear. I have a server action that deleted a cookie, and it seems that if it is called by a client component, it works, but if called by a server component it doesn't. Do server actions not count as server actions if they are called by a server component?

Comment: In that case, it just becomes part of the server component code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to use `set` method on actions. [from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options)

> Good to know: .set() is only available in a Server Action or Route
> Handler
>
> To "delete" a cookie, you must set a new cookie with the same name and
> an empty value. You can also set the maxAge to 0 to expire the cookie
> immediately.

example from same docs:

```
'use server'
 
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
 
async function create(data) {
  cookies().set({
    name: 'name',
    value: '',
    expires: new Date('2016-10-05'),
    path: '/', // For all paths
  })
}
```

[from this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49259), it might after 13.4.2

Comment: still getting the same error