# NextJS deleting cookie in server function throws an error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a service in which a nextjs app communicates with a separate, backend API. The API handles auth like this:

- Frontend sends login details to nextjs server
- Nextjs server sends those details to the API, and receives a credential
- Nextjs stores this credential in the browser session, using iron-session.

This has been working well, but I am trying to implement automatic credential cookie deletion in nextjs, such that:

- Server action makes request to API
- If API response is a 401, it means that the credential has expired since we last used it, so delete the cookie that contains the credential. The code looks like this:

```
export const deleteCookie = async () => {
  cookies().delete(sessionOptions.cookieName);
};
```

```
export async function fetchWrapper(...args) {
  var res = await fetch(...args);
  if (res.status === 401) {
    await deleteCookie();
  }
  return res;
}
```

`fetchWrapper` is then a drop-in replacement for fetch in server actions.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler
```

I am confused, since both the `fetchWrapper` file, and the file calling it, are both decorated with `use server`, and are definitely running on the server, otherwise the latter would not be able to decrypt the session to access the credential in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to delete cookie using Next.js server side action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509197/unable-to-delete-cookie-using-next-js-server-side-action)

Comment: @Taxel, not really, no, or at least it opens more questions that it answers. As I understand it, a server action runs on the server, regardless of whether it is called from a server or client component.